# How to use "..." as variable in class function

Tags: c++, function, class

Let's say i have this:

```
class Math  
{  
public:  
  int Add (int v1 , ... );  
}
```

how do i make the function "Add" to add all the numbers?

Comment: Read about [Variable Argument Lists using va_list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html).

Comment: thank you! i think i got it from this

Comment: I would suggest to not look at http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html Variadic (See the answers) templates offer a better alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variadic template function

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T Add(T v1, Args... rest)
{
    for (const T value : { rest... })
    {
        v1 += value;
    }
    return v1;
}
```

[Working example](http://cpp.sh/6ftyv)

Answer (score 1):

You can use variadic templates, ie:

```
int add(int a) {
    return a;
}

template<typename... Args>
int add(int a, Args... args) {
    return a + add(args...);
}
```

Comment: sorry, haven't use templates yet